# Select data from one table only with overlapping values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get only the rows that overlap on `Start` an `End`

| Id | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 6 | 8 |
| 4 | 9 | 10 |

So the result will be

| Id | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 6 | 8 |

Comment: what should "overlap on Start an End" mean?

Comment: I do no know how to compare values from one table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use exists logic along with the formula for the overlapping range problem:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.id <> t1.id AND t2.Start <= t1.End AND t2.End >= t1.Start
);
```

Comment: This does not work, it returns the initial table

Comment: @RheinmetallSkorpion Sorry, initial code was untested.  You may try the update.